# inject breeze service in angularjs + typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, breeze, angularjs-service

```
class Metadata {

    constructor(private breeze) {

        this.breeze.? // Ctrl+Space Nothing 

        breeze.? // Ctrl+Space Everything

    }

}

angular.module('bs.breeze', ['breeze.angular']);

// do nothing but you could
// create the window.breeze object
angular.module('bs.breeze').run(['breeze', function (breeze) { }]);


//get breeze metadata by hand
angular.module("bs.breeze").factory('metadata', [ 'breeze', (breeze) => new Metadata(breeze)]);
```

this.breeze.? shows nothing because "private breeze" has none declared type as you can see.

breeze.? shows everything because it does reference to module breeze declared in [breeze.d.ts](http://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

breeze and this.breeze are the same object

My problem here is how can use AngularJs standards injections like I'm doing in last line  when I'm injecting breeze service into metadata service and then when I'm coding Metadata class how can I use "this.breeze" and have TypeScript advantages like IntelliSense.

Finally, it's possible that this.breeze can be seen as breeze module for IntelliSense purposes or exists other way to implement this scenario?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `typeof` to refer to the type of a module. In this case since you have the parameter named `breeze`, you'll need to either rename the parameter or create an import for the global symbol `breeze` so you can actually refer to it:

```
import br = breeze;
class MyClass1 {
    constructor(private breeze: typeof br) {

    }
}

/*** or ***/

class MyClass2 {
    constructor(private br: typeof breeze) {

    }
}
```